# Why is the broadcast described as flag in the docs when it is actually an object?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In the **broadcasting messages** section http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages there is the following description

> To broadcast, simply add a broadcast flag to emit and send method
>   calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except
>   for the socket that starts it. Server

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});
```

The **broadcast** is an object. Why does the doc description refers it as flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally in the socket.io implementation, `broadcast` is a flag that is sent with an emit that tells the underlying infrastructure what to do.  See [the source for that flag here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/5ce06d3088660e9d78ad291d9ceb89ba10045d06/lib/socket.js#L38) and you can see [here in the source](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L127) where it tests for that flag on a socket to decide if a given `emit` should be broadcast.

The `broadcast` in `socket.broadcast.emit()` is indeed an object.

`broadcast` is also a method on the adapter object which is used internally by socket.io.  So, they've used the term for just about everything (flag, object, method).  The doc has a few of the different uses confused in the case you reference.

The socket.io doc is what it is (not nearly as good as it could be).  I find constant references to the source code on Github or even tracing into the execution in a debugger to be essential for understanding how things work.